# Select file by index from Files Collection

Tags: random, vbscript

I'm trying to access a file by index using vbs but Item does not work as I expected. I would rather not have to loop all files as I'm trying to avoid a treewalk. I recieve the error "Error:   Invalid procedure call or argument" on the line with colFiles.Item().

```
Randomize
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(fFolder.Path)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
Set objFile = colFiles.Item(Int(colFiles.Count * Rnd))
```

I'm sure it's obvious, but my searching only shows example using loops.

Comment: The is the shell interfaces and the wmi interfaces. FolderItems Object

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The FolderItems object represents the collection of items in a Shell folder. It contains properties and methods that allow you to retrieve information about the collection. 

This does do indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBScript does not support random/index access to the elements of the .Files collection. You'll have to For Each loop, pick a random file, and Exit the loop.

Update:

According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779003%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), you can use a 'name' (file name, file spec(?)) as parameter to .Item(), so you could keep an array of file names/specs, pick one randomly, and access the file. Whether that would be an improvement in your case, remains to be seen.

Comment: Ok, that is a shame - but does explain why I do not see examples. I thought all Collections supported item method, I must be confusing with another language.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification but I don't think that will help in my case.